# The image doesn´t appear in the website. Explorer path is already checked

Tags: html, image, visual-studio

The image which i want to have in the header doesn´t appear.

I checked the explorer path and capital letters. I already typed the whole path.

`<header><img src ="graphics/examplelogo.png" alt="Logo" height="150" width="600"></header>`

Image doesn´t appear.

Answer (score 0):

you need a slash before `graphics/examplelogo.png`. So, your code should be:

```
<header>
    <img src="/graphics/examplelogo.png" alt="Logo" height="150" width="600">
</header>
```